# is it really good idea to use asyncio with files

Tags: python, concurrency, httprequest, python-asyncio

I've been reading and watching videos a lot about asyncio in python, but there's something I can't wrap my head around.

I understand that asyncio is great when dealing with databases or http requests, because database management systems and http servers can handle multiple rapid requests, but...

How can it be good for files, writing in particular..

Let's discuss this case with this code that is running on a server as fastAPI webApp.

> @app.get('/end_point')
> async function ()
>     do_something()
>     **await** write_to_a_file
>     do_more_stuff_and_return

Now, as a server, it may get like 50, 100, or even more rapid requests that will trigger this function, yes **await** will pause the next instruction inside *function()* , but if there are multiple requests coming this *function* will start so many times and execute multiple write attempt at once to the file, which may corrupt the data inside.

That's why I can't really understand how it is recommended to use asyncio for files.

Am I getting something wrong here?
Is there a way to instruct the event_loop to give this higher priority to that *function* event or some another way to avoid this?

What I'm doing now is delaying writing files until I have X amount of data to write [write in bursts], but I still think that any function that does interaction with files shouldn't be async function.

But then, I don't know how am I going to deal with tons of requests....
Your thoughts will be highly appreciated as I'm having a hard time with this.

thanks, have a good day.

I'm trying to write data to file, but the server will surly receive bursts of requests.
So in a way I don't know how to handle this situation, and I fear the corruption of data.

Comment: If they are all writing to the *same* file, then you might not get the order you expect; if they each write to a *different* file, then you might as well let the OS handle the scheduling for you.

Comment: Asyncio contains synchronization primitives, which can be used to serialize access to a specific resource (i.e., prevent multiple tasks from messing with the same file).  https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio-sync

Comment: @ScottHunter they are all writing to the same file...
But I'm just curios , how to let the OS handle the scheduling for me? Can it be useful if they're all writing to the same file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to write data to file, but the server will surly receive
> bursts of requests. So in a way I don't know how to handle this
> situation, and I fear the corruption of data.

Yes, corruption could happen from time to time especially if you use `aiofiles`. If I'm not wrong it uses threads to achieve this.

I think you have two options here:

1. **Using lock and background tasks**: in FastApi(since you mentioned) you can do the writing in the [background](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/) (after sending the respond to the user), and there, acquire a [lock object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Lock) for writing to the file.
2. **Queue the messages for writing**: instead of directly writing to the file, put them on a queue and let another task/process get do the writing part.

In both cases user won't wait for writing to be finished and get the response immediately and the writing part will happen in sync.

Comment: interesting...
I think the queuing is a good solution.

For now I'm doing this: when a request that needs data to be written it calls a function, this function will wait 3 minutes and then write *buffer* data to the file, in the mean time I collect data that need to be written to the file, once the data is written the *buffer* variable will be reset.

with queuing this may get even better, because I'd get sure that nothing gets pushed to the *buffer* dict while the file is being written.

Comment: But I wonder, should I use threading for ? Or even parallelization (note that I never used any of those before and I don't know when to use them)......  
Also, should I move to DB as soon as possible instead of relying on a JSON file?

Comment: @AbdAlhaleemBakkor Deciding to choose between async/threads/processes is another topic. Generally if you're doing cpu-bound tasks, it's usually better to spawn a new process but it comes with its own complexity. By "*I collect data*", if it comes from io call, you can handle all with just asyncio.